# Generate RSA private-public key pair using Helm

Tags: rsa, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-secrets, key-pair

Helm allows generating a new RSA 4096 private key using the `genPrivateKey` function which I use to generate a key and store it in a K8s secret. How can I use Helm to create a public key for the generated private key?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
{{- $cert := genSelfSignedCertWithKey "" (list) (list) 3650 (genPrivateKey "rsa") }}
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: {{ .Values.secretName }}
type: kubernetes.io/tls
data:
  tls.crt: |
    {{ $cert.Cert | b64enc }}
  tls.key: |
    {{ $cert.Key | b64enc }}
```

Comment: This will generate a certificate, not a public key. What the OP needs is a key pair, that's not the solution.

Comment: @AleRinaldi couldn't we generate the certificate, extract the public key, then throw away the certificate?