# extract public RSA key from private key using Helm

Tags: go, kubernetes, jwt, rsa, kubernetes-helm

How can I extract the public key from the generated private key (by using genPrivateKey helm function) into a second field in the secret?
I need the public/private key-pair for JWT.
In extend, how would I use a key password / jwtkey?

I found my exact question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72859835/generate-rsa-private-public-key-pair-using-helm)
Sadly, there is only an answer on how to get a cert, but not the public key.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
data:
  # TODO use jwtkey when generating private key
  {{- $privateKey := (genPrivateKey "rsa") }}
  private.pem: |
    {{ $privateKey | b64enc }}
  # TODO extract rsa public key
  public.pem: |
    {{ $publicKey | b64enc }}
```

Comment: I don't see anything in the [Sprig cryptographic functions](https://masterminds.github.io/sprig/crypto.html) that would create an RSA private key, as distinct from an X.509 certificate.  You also may not want to use `genPrivateKey` like this, since a new key pair will be generated every time you run `helm upgrade`.  Consider adding a bounty to the other question you cited rather than re-asking it.